# Protractor - Appium - iOS - Multiple real Devices - Test Automation

Tags: protractor, appium, mobile-devices

I am new to Appium.

I am able to run protractor e2e tests, on 1 Android device connected to MAc using USB cable. Appium server started as shown below.

appium -a 127.0.0.1 -U DEVICEID

however this does not seem to be ideal option when planning to run on multiple devices (around 20 iOS, Android devices).

Would you please advise, if its possible to run tests on Multiple Android + iOS Devices over wi-fi, by specifying device details in Protractor.conf.js.

Kindly please share your thoughts or experience on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run same test on multiple devices. All you need to do to run Appium ports as many as you want to run on devices. Mention the UDID and port in your script and run it. For more info, read [this](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?java#running-tests).